# ClassNotFoundException - Unable to instantiate BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, apk, classnotfoundexception, dex

I have a `Broadcastreceiver` which checks for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` and it crashes sometimes with message:

```
04-05 18:23:47.080    5561-5561/tenkol.design.com.imbrecords E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.NetworkChangeReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.NetworkChangeReceiver
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2541)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.NetworkChangeReceiver
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2536)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The aim of receiver is simple - jsut make toast when internet connection is gone.

Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and the receiver itself:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    String status = InternetConnection.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    if (status != null) {
        if (status.equals("Not connected to Internet")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.lost_internet_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the methods it uses:

```
public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = InternetConnection.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == InternetConnection.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
```

Any ideas what causes crashes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ClassNotFoundException` is an indication that your app's APK has not been built correctly. It seems to be a `dex` build error; the clue here is that the exception is thrown by the `BaseDexClassLoader.findClass()` method.

I have observed this error in the following situations previously:

**1.** I was using a physical device (i.e. not an emulator) that had Kitkat with ART enabled. When I ran the app on another Kitkat device with Dalvik runtime, the error seemed to have vanished.

**2.** The same problem arose due to a `.dex` build error which occurred when I shifted the SVN to another location. I deleted the old project entirely and created a new repository from the original project on my computer, and after rebuilding the project entirely the error did not reappear.

**3.** If using Eclipse with Maven, and you have enabled `multidex`, then try disabling it and building the project. If using Android Studio, set `multiDexEnabled = false`. This is a known cause of this error.

Basically you need to rebuild the project correctly and the error will go away.

Comment: Thanks! I will do this and observe for some time. If it solves problem I mark your answer