# What does "multiDexEnabled true" mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-build-tools

What is meant by "multiDexEnabled true" in Android gradle. Why do we use this? What is the effect if it is enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android support multidex library implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925264/android-support-multidex-library-implementation)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in
>   the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled
>   code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits
>   the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX
>   file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods,
>   and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that
>   you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX
>   file, known as a multidex configuration.

You should read official guide line about **[Building Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)**

Comment: Why is this not enabled by default?

Comment: @fobbymaster have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226290/default-value-of-boolean-in-java

Comment: well one reason for it to be false is this bug :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/29458974/1397821

Answer (score 40):

Android applications by default have SingleDex support which limits your application to have only 65536 methods(references). So multidexEnabled = true simply means that now you can write more than 65536 methods(references) in your application.

## But I will never write 65536 methods!

When we say the number of methods, it means

> methods written by you + Android Framework methods + Third party
> library (eg Volley, Retrofit, Facebook SDK etc) methods.

I have read somewhere in a post that
App Compat 24.2.1 contains 16.5k methods
Google Play Services GCM 9.6.1 contains 16.7k methods.
So if you have just written a simple Hello world application which has App Compat 24.2.1 then your application is already having **16.7k** methods.

### How to enable multidex support

> it depends on minSdkVersion of your app

If minSdkVersion >= 21 then you can enable it by writing multidexEnabled = true
if minSdkVersion <21 then you will have to include [Multidex Compatibily library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex) in your gradle.
See more on [enabling multidex support](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

### Advantage of multiDex

multidex allows your applications to have more third-party libraries.

### More on .dex files

Android applications are compiled into a .dex file/files which in turn zipped to a single .apk file. .dex files have bytecodes which are used by Dalvik Virtual Machine(DVM).
You can read more on [.dex and DVM](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run)

Comment: It still will have the 64k limit per `.dex` - but as the name suggests, it's multi-dex (more than one dex file).

Comment: is there any problem in building an app with more than 64k methods

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to build apps with over 64k methods. For more information see here http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html