# MissingPluginException exception when a firebase anonymous sign-in with flutter (windows) app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-desktop

I recently started out with flutter for windows. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC) firebase and flutter tutorial. At lecture 4, I am getting error with Firebase Auth:

> flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInAnonymously on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

I think the problem is because I am building for windows. I don't know how to add firebase to windows application. Any help is appreciated

Here is the complete log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
Waiting for Windows to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60688/97Ok8iT1Hjo=/ws
Syncing files to device Windows...
flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInAnonymously on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
flutter: error signing in
```

***EDIT 1***

pubspec.yaml file (dependencies section)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
```

***EDIT 2***

I updated the dependencies to use following versions:

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+3
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
```

This is what my main function looks like:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Try building after doing a `flutter clean`

Comment: Have you added the required dependency in yaml file? And if you have, did you run the command `flutter pub get` to download the updated dependencies?

Comment: @BugsHappen yes I did

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file here, the dependencies part only?

Comment: @HardikSachan please add firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1 and try again

Comment: @HardikSachan Have got this exception fixed?

Comment: same issue, did you get any solution?

Comment: I got this fixed just by completely stopping then starting the app again.

Answer (score 5):

You are just hot reloading or hot restarting your flutter after adding the `await Firebase.initializeApp();` in your **void main()** function.

**Just Stop your main.dart process and run it again from the begining -- thats it, now your app gets integrated with firebase!**

note: during running some may face issues with the **Multidex error** refer link: [D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 71610 > 65536)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591958/flutter-firestore-causing-d8-cannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file) to solve the error **or** just add:

> > in your project level >>  android >> app >> build.gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
...

multiDexEnabled true
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but the actual issue is that `flutter_core` does not actually **support** Windows.
It only supports Android, iOS, MacOS & Web (See the [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) package on pub.dev).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

incase your running the app on android and your `MainActivity` has this import statement:

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
```

you might have to change it to this instead:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

*make sure you enable **signin** method in console firebase
https://console.firebase.google.com*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> But now I am getting the following error:
>
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

As mentioned in [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3212#issuecomment-676112777), You need to set `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0` in your dependencies in `android/build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But I am trying to use it in windows build. How do I initialize firebase for windows build?

Comment: There is a package fb_auth. You can check it. https://pub.dev/packages/fb_auth. As they noticed in the package info, it works on Windows too.

Comment: Is there a similar package for firestore as well?